# All linear transformations $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are multiplication by a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In *Linear Algebra Done Wrong* by Sheldon Axler, there's a proof of "all linear transformations $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are multiplication by a constant". It goes like this:
$$
T: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
T(x) = T(x \times 1) = xT(1) = xa = ax
$$

My question is: $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}$ - so how come can we "move it out" of the transformation? The definition of a linear transformation allows to do such a thing only with scalars. I see that if we have vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ than vectors and scalars in this space are in some sense "the same", but why exactly is this allowed? If an object fits both the definition of a vector and a scalar, it can be treated as both? Why?

Comment: I guess you dont like that book ? The $x$ is a scalar and $1$ is a vector.

Comment: The title of the book that I wrote is Linear Algebra Done Right (Sergei Treil is the author of Linear Algebra Done Wrong). The proof above does not come from my book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Axler here views the vector $x$ the same as the scalar (with value $x$) multiplied by the vector $1$, and as you say, scalars can be moved out of the transformation.